# How do I get masked date in model from input in angular using ui-mask?

Tags: angularjs, mask, input-mask

I have a view which requires that the user enter their birthdate into a textbox.

I am using the mask directive from UI-Utils.

My view has this input element in it:

```
<input ui-mask="99/99/9999" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" name="uBirthdate" ng-model="user.birthdate" required/>
```

and in my controller I have the scope set up as

```
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, myService){

    $scope.user = registerService.getCurrentUser();

    $scope.submit = function () {
        //do something with $scope.user.birthdate
    };

    }
});
```

My issue is that in my controller, the birthdate property contains the value from the input WITHOUT the masking characters so an input of

`11/20/1980` in the view becomes `11201980` as a property on the $scope

How can I make sure I have a valid masked date to work with in my controller? Just FYI, this date will be sent as JSON in a POST request to my server.

Answer (score 45):

Upgrade to the lastest angular-ui and use the following syntax

```
ui-mask="99/99/9999" model-view-value="true"
```

The model-view-value will keep the mask on your model object.

Comment: Is there any way for it to do 12/19/9999 so that you couldn't type in invalid dates.

Comment: I would use a client side validation library for checking valid dates instead of using the mask for this purpose

Comment: [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) can be added to check for client side validation as @map7 mentioned.

Comment: PixMach may have been looking for what I was after which is a UI mask on invalid dates that prevents invalid input. I.e. not just checking for an invalid state. The JQuery UI control at [Date mask](http://keith-wood.name/dateEntry.html) is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

try this one
https://github.com/candreoliveira/ngMask
help full for all mask

Answer (score -2):

as a string:

```
var string = '11201980';
var month = string.substring(0,2);
var day = string.substring(2,4);
var year = string.substring(4,8);
var birthday = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
```

then, as a Date:

```
var birthdate = new Date(birthday);
```